# Using Native Base with React Native Elements

Tags: react-native, native-base, react-native-elements, react-native-vector-icons

I recently installed Native Base, while I have been using React Native Elements, it just isn't enough. My build keeps failing because the same target produces two different paths because, Native Base already has react-native-vector-icons built into it, but I can't delete it because React Native Elements needs it in order to run. What should I do in this situation? Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: So you are saying that you have `react-native-vector-icons` already implemented somewhere else?

Comment: Well, it seems that both UI Toolkit required it.

Comment: You probably don't need to include both UI libraries, just use one or make your own UI components. Using two UI libraries will just increase the overhead in your project.

Comment: @PritishVaidya, I am using both of the libraries because I need components from both of them.

Comment: @RachidRhafour, Yes, NB comes with a pre-installed version of RNVI. While RNE requires it to be installed separately.

Comment: @Minter and if you keep the one that NB pre-install and remove the one you installed previously, I guess somehow you can point to the one that NB is using to RNE to use it too.

Comment: @RachidRhafour, If I do that, I get a vulnerability issue from npm, because RNVI is a dependency of RNE

Comment: Well all I can suggest is to create an issue in NB or/ RNE .
if i have some time this weekend, I'll try to do the same and reproduce your issue and see if I can fix it.

Comment: @RachidRhafour, that would just be marvellous. Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Thanks, everyone, I just implemented what I needed from RNE in a separate file and removed RNE along with RNVI.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can't actually do that. So I made custom components based on the RNE components.